# How to join two objects

Tags: modeling, objects

At first, they were the same object, but after saving it they got separated

[image]

[image: The object got seperated]

before it looks like this[image: Before Saving it]

How to combine both objects

Comment: Select the 2 objects and Ctrl J?

Comment: Ctrl J was Combining two objects, but the object did not look like before.

Comment: OK but nobody can tell how it happened, if you want one unique object you need to join with Ctrl J, then in Edit mode select the icing with L and move it as you want

Comment: As @moonboots says, we cannot tell how it happened, we cannot go back in time and see how the objects looked and were set up before. I can only imagine there were some modifiers or whatever or changes in scaling etc. that somehow caused this. I can only highly recommend (because I'm quite sure this does not happen in the donut tutorial) to pay close attention when watching tutorials as a beginner, because you might have done something accidentally wrong.

Comment: So I just saw in your file you have put animation keyframes on the icing and the donut which will keep them in the location where they are. I guess then you have probably moved them in a different place without fixing this with a new keyframe. Then saved the file and since there is no keyframe for the new position, Blender reads the existing keyframes and puts the objects there. Or simply changing from one frame to another will reset the location as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get them combined by selecting them both and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join them or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to parent the top layer to the bottom layer.

Answer (score 0):

Move the first one down by selecting it, pressing control G, then Y and move your mouse down until it's at your desired location. Once you've done that, hit ctrl-J to join them together.